# Is escaping output from MySQL server necessary if data being retrieved has already been sanitized?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, escaping

I'm interested to know whether or not it is necessary to escape output from a MySQL server if the data that is being retrieved has already been filtered when the user submitted a form.

Example:
1. The user submits a form with a comment for a blog post.
2. On form submission, prior to sending data to MySQL server, their input is filtered with `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` to prevent injection attacks.
3. Once the data has been posted to server, the user is rerouted to another screen where they can view their comment.
4. When retrieving their comment from the server (which has stored the filtered input), is it necessary to escape this output as well?

Here's the main issue for me. I'm taking user input from a form (for a blog post), sanitizing it with `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`, and then posting it to the MySQL server. If I retrieve this information from the server and display it in html, there are no issues. HOWEVER, I have been reading that you should ALWAYS escape output from servers as well. So I escaped the same post with `htmlspecialchars()`. Now, I have the issue that ALL special chars (including parentheses, and any quotes that are used by the user in their post) are coming back in their escaped html format. Not user friendly whatsoever.

What is the best work around for this, or is it even necessary to escape the output if it is coming from the server and has already been sanitized on user input?

Comment: HTML encode outputs, not inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sanitization is *not* the same as escaping, and you should make sure not to confuse the two.

*Sanitization* is removing unwanted input. That is, if the user adds a `<script>` tag to their input, and you don't want their input to include `<script>` tags, then removing that `<script>` tag would be sanitization. Sanitization is *not* escaping data for an output context.

*Escaping* is properly encoding data for an output context. For example, to prevent HTML injection, you might call  `htmlspecialchars()` to correctly encode `&` as `&amp;`. To prevent SQL injection, you might use `mysqli::real_escape_string()` to convert `'` to `\'`. (Though it would be *highly* preferable to use prepared statements / parameterized queries to prevent having to worry about sql injection or escaping at all.)

*Importantly*, escaping is context-specific. An escaping you use for HTML is not necessarily valid or sufficient for SQL (or vice-versa, or any other output context).

The problem with `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` is that that it's poorly named: it's doing both in one step, which is confusing for your database (since your database now has html-encoded data), and confusing for output (because now you have already-escaped data that is vulnerable to being multiply-escaped).

Instead, you should explicitly separate your sanitization and escaping efforts. *Only* sanitize data on input that you don't want to persist. *Only* escape data on output, and according to its proper output context.

The reason you want to store raw (pre-output-escaped) data in the database is so that if you ever need to output to a different context (e.g. now you're dong JSON output, or you need to write it to a file, or actually see what the raw data is), you won't need to unescape it first. (If you really have to, you might reasonably store a pre-escaped copy in a separate column, but you should always have your original data available.) It also makes the rule simple: always sanitize input; always escape output.

Comment: Great answer, I wish more people would take the time to understand these fundamental things :-)